# Изменяется текст и у всех объектов цикла при отправке post запроса на ajax

Tags: javascript

```
Есть такой скрипт (Лайк к посту):




    $('a.like').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $.post('{% url "images:image_like" %}', {
          id: $(this).data('id'),
          csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
        },
        function(data) {
          if (data['status'] == 'like') {
            $('i.like-text').text('favorite');
          } else {
            $('i.like-text').text('favorite_border');
          }
          previous_like_count = parseInt($('li.image_like_counts').text());
          if (data['status'] == 'like') {
            $('li.image_like_counts').text(previous_like_count += 1)
          } else {
            $('li.image_like_counts').text(previous_like_count -= 1)
          }
        }
      )
    })
    <a class="nav-link like" data-id="{{ image.id }}" href="#">
      <i class="material-icons like-text"
         style="color:#de2d2d;"
         data-toggle="tooltip"
         data-placement="top"
         data-html="true"
         title="<p> Понравилось </p> {% for liked_user in image.users_like.all %}{{ liked_user.username }}{% endfor %}">
          {% if request.user in image.users_like.all %} favorite {% else %} favorite_border {% endif %}
      </i>
    </a>




При нажатии на который `POST-запрос` отправляется как надо, к одному конкретному объекту. Но текст изменяется на всех объектах цикла. Как быть?




{% for image in images %}
    <div class="media" style="border-radius: 0;">
         <img src="/media/{{ image.author.profile.photo }}" class="mr-3" style="width: 45px; border-radius: 50%;" 
data-toggle="tooltip" 
data-placement="top" 
title="{{ image.author.username }}">
    <div class="media-body">
         <div class="media-title">{{ image.author.username }} <br>
              <span class="media-date">{{ image.created }}</span></div>
          </div>
    </div>
    {% if image.url %}
       <img class="card-img-top" style="border: none;" src="{{ image.url }}">
    {% else %}
        <img class="card-img-top" style="border: none;" src="/media/{{ image.image }}" >
        {% endif %}
        <div class="media" style="border-radius: 0;">
            <div class="media-body">
                 <ul class="nav justify-content row">
                      <li class="selected nav-item col-sm-1">
                        <a class="nav-link like" data-id="{{ image.id }}" href="#">
                            <i class="material-icons like-text"
                               style="color:#de2d2d;"
                               data-toggle="tooltip"
                               data-placement="top"
                               data-html="true"
                               title="<p> Понравилось </p> {% for liked_user in image.users_like.all %}     {{liked_user.username }}{% endfor %}">
                            {% if request.user in image.users_like.all %} favorite {% else %}    favorite_border {% endif %}
                            </i>
                        </a>
                      </li>
                        <li class="col-sm-8 image_like_counts">{{ image.users_like.count }}</li>

                    </ul>
                    </div>
        </div>
            </li> <br>

        {% endfor %}
```

Comment: выбирать конкретный элемент, а не все на странице

Comment: и как? Если у меня код в цикле

Comment: не вижу в приведенном коде цикла

Comment: прикрепил #html

Answer (score 0):

Уточняйте селекторы по id, например:

```js
var id = $(this).data(`id`);
$(`li.image_like_counts[data-id=${id}]`)
```

---

Но, возможно, лучше вам использовать `$(this)`. Тогда найти нужные элементы можно так

```js
$('a.like').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var parent = $(this).closest('.media-body');
    var like_text = parent.find('i.like-text');
    var image_like_counts = parent.find('li.image_like_counts');

    $.post('{% url "images:image_like" %}',
        {
            id: $(this).data('id'),
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
        },
        function (data) {
            if (data['status'] == 'like') {
                like_text.text('favorite');
            } else {
                like_text.text('favorite_border');
            }
            previous_like_count = parseInt(image_like_counts.text());
            if(data['status'] == 'like') {
                image_like_counts.text(previous_like_count += 1)
            } else {
                image_like_counts.text(previous_like_count -= 1)
            }
        }
    )
})
```

Comment: Спасибо, текст у "like_text" меняется, а "image_like_counts" не хочет

Comment: @Максим, исправил опечатку и подкорректировал в соответствии с дополненным html.